# Change Text Color CSS3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, textcolor

I am trying to change the text color of this link, I am using a twitter bootstrap template. I can change the size, font, padding, and background color of this text but I cannot change the text color it's self. I am also using a font I got online.

HTML:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- You'll want to use a responsive image option so this logo looks good on devices - I recommend using something like retina.js (do a quick Google search for it and you'll find it) -->
            @Html.ActionLink("Fat", "Index", new { controller = "Home" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })<br />
            @Html.ActionLink("Savage", "Index", new { controller = "Home" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-brand {
    font-family: 'TribecaRegular';
    color: green;
    font-size:xx-large;
    padding-right: 150px;
}
```

the font color is always grey never anything else.

Comment: I think .navbar-brand has an `<a>` tag inside of it. If that's the case, you need to reference the `<a>` tag to change the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.navbar-brand` is colored by bootstrap.

The rule used by bootstrap is `.navbar-default .navbar-brand {...}`

So you need to create an equal or higher specificity rule

```
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    font-family: 'TribecaRegular';
    color: green;
    font-size:xx-large;
    padding-right: 150px;
}
```

The above will work if it is placed after the bootstrap rule.

Or you could define it with `.navbar-default a.navbar-brand` so that it is used regardless of where you place the rule.

Answer (score 2):

You are not hitting the span tag, you need to do something like this:

```
.navbar-brand span{

    color:green;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

.navbar-brand doesn't exist but if you change it to the correct scope and are still seeing a problem, target the span tag as Anders suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Could always just assign an ID tag to whatever text is needing to be change.

```
.navbar-header #someID{
    color: green;
}
```

Or if you want to hit all of that element, then do as the other posters have said, target the  tag